# Find specific children components regardless of depth in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to return an array of child components that match a particular name inside a parent component.

For example:

```
React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).filter(child => ['TextInput'].includes(child.type.name));
```

So even if I have:

```
<Form>
  <div>
    <TextInput />
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <TextInput />
    </div>
  </div>
</Form>
```

I would be able to return an array of those two `TextInput` components.

However because of the nesting of these elements/components the filter only loops the once through the first depth...

I've tried to do this recursively using `flatMap` which I understood would do this:

```
React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).flatMap(child => ['TextInput'].includes(child.type.name));
```

However it doesn't seem to have worked as I expected... is there an alternative way of finding the matching components regardless of the depth of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a recursive function:

```
function walkAllChildren(root, callback) {
  function walk(e, parents) {
    callback(e, parents);
    const newParents = [...parents, e];
    React.Children.toArray(e.props?.children).forEach((c) => {
      walk(c, newParents);
    });
  }
  walk(root, []);
}

walkAllChildren(
  <main>
    <div>
      <TextInput />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        Hello!
        <TextInput />
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>,
  (e, parents) => {
    if (e.type?.name === "TextInput") {
      console.log(e, parents);
    }
  },
);
```

prints out

```
{type: ƒ TextInput(), key: ".0", ref: null, props: Object, _owner: FiberNode…}
(2) [Object, Object]
{type: ƒ TextInput(), key: ".1", ref: null, props: Object, _owner: FiberNode…}
(3) [Object, Object, Object]
```

(and expanding the `Object` arrays would show the ancestry of each TextInput).

EDIT: the same as TypeScript, if you need the types:

```
function walkAllChildren(
  root: React.ReactNode,
  callback: (
    element: React.ReactNode,
    parents: readonly React.ReactNode[]
  ) => void
) {
  function walk(element: React.ReactNode, parents: readonly React.ReactNode[]) {
    if (element === null || element === undefined) return;
    callback(element, parents);
    const newParents = [...parents, element];
    const children = (element as any).props?.children;
    React.Children.toArray(children).forEach((child) => {
      walk(child, newParents);
    });
  }
  walk(root, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's finding the elements. Should I be able to call methods on those returned elements though? I've tried to access them but can only get at the properties but returns a function not found when trying to call a method on it.

Comment: For example I was hoping to be able to do: `this.formFields[0].exampleMethod()` which would call that method on the first child in the returned array.

Comment: Ah figured it out... had to add a ref to the `TextInput` and then I can access the method like so: `this.formFields[0].ref.current.exampleMethod()`. Ends up being quite a bit of work to access React child components from others :D